# My exit-node suddenly lost all of its consensus weight, I don't know where to start troubleshooting

Tags: exit-relays, consensus

The node in question is the following:

https://atlas.torproject.org/#details/3D7E274A87D9A89AF064C13D1EE4CA1F184F2600

The node has been restarted recently in hope of that fixing it, alas to no avail. As you can see the node itself still has all the proper flags, stable, valid, exit, fast etc.

I have not changed anything in my torrc file. Any kind of input would be helpful. Also the servers bandwidth is dedicated.

Comment: Nothing comes to mind, except the possibility the the bandwidth authorities had failed to measure the consensus weight properly, or your node, somehow, reported a value of 0 at some time.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the votes for the individual directory authorities, it appears that gabelmoo and longclaw don't have Measured lines for your relay. moria1 and tor26 measure your node just fine. I worry that there's nothing you can do on your end to fix it, as it is a problem with the bandwidth authorities measurement code. I'm gabelmoo's operator and I'll try to fix it, but I have no idea about the inner workings of the bwauth code. Hopefully you'll be measured again within a day.

Comment: just out of curiosity, how would you try to fix it?

Comment: I removed the cache files ad restarted the bwauth processes

Comment: I see, did you notice a difference already?

Comment: no :( Keeping an eye out

Comment: I've recently changed my exit node back to a regular relay node and within minutes its consensus started climbing again. Currently at 7710 -> https://atlas.torproject.org/#details/3D7E274A87D9A89AF064C13D1EE4CA1F184F2600